# Why this trivial opengl program uses 100% cpu?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, opengl, nvidia

The following opengl code is specifically made to be very GPU-heavy and this forces the CPU to wait for a bit while the GPU finishes its work. In particular, it does so at the `glFinish()` call where the CPU waits for a measured 99.87% of the time per frame. The program runs at 10 fps on my system (windows 10, gtx1070) and Vsync disabled. This is all expected, if it wasn't for the fact that while the CPU is supposed to wait, it inexplicably uses 100% CPU time, causing overheating.

After testing on 6 systems with intel gpus, 4 with amd gpus and 5 with nvidia gpus, only those with nvidia gpus have the problem. All i can conclude so far is that this problem is nvidia-specific and opengl-specific. Directx apps don't show the problem, in fact, it is possible to reproduce this problem on Firefox by running a gpu-maxing webgl page with ANGLE disabled (doesn't happen with angle enabled).

I compile with the following:

```
C:\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe %~dp0\main.c -o %~dp0\main.exe -static-libgcc -std=c11 -ggdb -O2 -Wall -BC:\mingw64\bin\ -LC:\mingw64\lib\ -IC:\mingw64\include\ -lgdi32 -lopengl32
```

Minimal code (i suggest to tweak the fragment shader so that you hit around 10 fps as well, makes the problem more apparent):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

typedef signed long long int GLsizeiptr;
typedef char GLchar;

#define GL_ARRAY_BUFFER     0x8892
#define GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW     0x88E8
#define GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER  0x8B30
#define GL_VERTEX_SHADER    0x8B31

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    HDC hdc;
    {
        WNDCLASS wc;
        memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
        wc.style         = CS_OWNDC;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        wc.lpszClassName = "gldemo";
        if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return 0;

        HWND hwnd = CreateWindow("gldemo", "Demo", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1920/2, 1080/2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        
        const PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {0,0, PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        SetPixelFormat(hdc, ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd), &pfd);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, wglCreateContext(hdc));
        
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    
    void (*glGenBuffers)(GLsizei, GLuint *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    void (*glBindBuffer)(GLenum, GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
    void (*glBufferData)(GLenum, GLsizeiptr, void *, GLenum) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
    GLuint (*glCreateShader)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
    void (*glAttachShader)(GLuint, GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glAttachShader");
    void (*glCompileShader)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
    void (*glShaderSource)(GLuint, GLuint, const char **, const GLint *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glShaderSource");
    void (*glEnableVertexAttribArray)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLuint (*glGetAttribLocation)(GLuint, GLchar *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glGetAttribLocation");
    void (*glVertexAttribPointer)(GLuint, GLint, GLenum, GLboolean, GLsizei, void *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glVertexAttribPointer");
    GLuint (*glCreateProgram)() = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
    void (*glLinkProgram)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram");
    void (*glUseProgram)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glUseProgram");
    
    const char *g_vertCode =
        "#version 420\n"
        "in vec3 vertexPosition;"
        "void main() {gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.xyz, 1.);}";
        
    const char *g_fragCode =
        "#version 420\n"
        "void main() {"
            "float res = 0.5;"
            "for (int t=0;t<58000;t++) {" // tweak this to make sure you're outputting ~10 fps. 58000 is ok for a gtx 1070. 
                "res = fract(sin(dot(gl_FragCoord.xy+res, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);"
            "}"
            "gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(res)*0.4, 1.0);"
        "}";
    
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    
    GLuint vertshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertshader, 1, &g_vertCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertshader);
    glAttachShader(prog, vertshader);
    
    GLuint fragshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragshader, 1, &g_fragCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(fragshader);
    glAttachShader(prog, fragshader);
    
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glUseProgram(prog);
    
    GLuint attribVertexPosition = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "vertexPosition");
    
    float verts[4*3] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f};
    
    GLuint vboId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*3*4, verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribVertexPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribVertexPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 12, (void*)0);
    
    for (;;) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        //__asm__("int $3");
        glFinish(); // Halts here with 100% cpu on my system.
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
        
        MSG msg; char done = 0;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) done = 1;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (done) break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try disabling vsync and limiting the FPS with `Sleep()`.

Comment: Are you sure that VSYNC is active? Some drivers can be configured to override an application's VSYNC settings. With my Nvidia drivers, in the Nvidia Control Panel, under "Manage 3D settings", you can set "Vertical sync" to "Use the 3D application setting" or force it to "On" or "Off", which will override the application's setting.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i can tell with msi afterburner. the gpu can run the program at 400 fps so if afterburner says it's only 120, equal to my monitor's refresh rate, then it is active. i used exactly the nvidia driver method you described to turn vsync on/off while testing because it works well enough.

Comment: @tuket OP doesn't seem to use GLFW.

Comment: @user2464424 I have an impression that `SwapBuffers()` on some drives uses a busy loop to wait for the right moment to swap. You could try estimating how much it's going to wait, then sleep a slightly smaller amount (e.g. 1 ms less) before calling it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is that the case with vsync off as well? Because the problem persists even with vsync off.

Comment: I was talking about vsync being on. I'm not sure what *exactly* hogs cpu when vsync is off, but it's not that surprising when you don't limit your FPS in any way. Adding `Sleep` should help.

Comment: You are requesting that your program render whenever it can. When rendering code is trivial your program uses up all available CPU resources. Why does that surprise you?

Comment: Yes you need to add for example `Sleep(20);` into your last `for` loop otherwise your CPU side code will go on full throttle (has nothing to do with OpenGL rendering)... You can even use dynamic delay times `20-elapsed_time_from_last_iteration` to get more stable behavior from timing aspect where `20 ms` is the `1000/fps`

Comment: @IInspectable The cpu workload is the trivial part. On the other hand, the gpu workload is so great that the cpu is spending 99.87% of its time stuck in one of the gl* calls waiting for the gpu to finish (and that's with vsync off). Somehow, the cpu simply waiting around uses 100% cpu.

Comment: Yes. Actively waiting consumes CPU resources. It's almost like you expect CPU resources spent without your program making forward progress would not count towards CPU resources spent.

Comment: @IInspectable Well the intel laptop doesn't have the problem, meaning that there is at least one example of a wait implementation that doesn't overheat the cpu.

Comment: That's rather an example of someone jumping to conclusions. An integrated GPU is generally less powerful than a dedicated chip. Who knows, maybe your laptop is just slow enough so that the CPU actually needs to wait on the OpenGL calls to retire.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, so i won't mark it as one, but i can provide a workaround for now.

The idea is that the `glFlush` function guarantees that the gpu has started its processing, so we can, on paper, insert a wait after `glFlush` and before `glFinish` to cut down on the amount of time `glFinish` spends frying the cpu.
This is only viable if the resolution of the waiting function is at worst 1ms. If you use `Sleep`, or any other function in the Windows API that has a tweakable timeout, this can be set by calling `timeBeginPeriod(1)` at the start of the program.
To make sure the wait doesn't overshoot, which can cause the gpu to become idle, the formula used for waiting in the next frame is the time just spent by the wait plus the residual time spent on `glFinish` minus 0.5 milliseconds.

The result of all this is that the gpu stays well-fed at 100% usage according to the Task Manager yet the cpu utilization only starts to increase significantly if the time that vanilla `glFinish` would have spent gets lower than 4 ms and the mechanism disengages itself entirely if it gets lower than roughly 1.5 ms.
In an actual implementation one might consider inserting the `SwapBuffers` call inside the timed area to include in the calculation whatever frame-limiting systems might be in place and perhaps using `Waitable Timers` instead of `Sleep`.

Compiling with:

```
C:\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe %~dp0\main.c -o %~dp0\main.exe -static-libgcc -std=c11 -ggdb -O2 -Wall -BC:\mingw64\bin\ -LC:\mingw64\lib\ -IC:\mingw64\include\ -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm
```

Updated code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

typedef signed long long int GLsizeiptr;
typedef char GLchar;

#define GL_ARRAY_BUFFER     0x8892
#define GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW     0x88E8
#define GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER  0x8B30
#define GL_VERTEX_SHADER    0x8B31

LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
unsigned long long int elapsedMicroseconds(LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime) {
    LARGE_INTEGER EndingTime;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    return (1000000*(EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart))/Frequency.QuadPart;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
    timeBeginPeriod(1);
    
    HDC hdc;
    {
        WNDCLASS wc;
        memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
        wc.style         = CS_OWNDC;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        wc.lpszClassName = "gldemo";
        if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return 0;

        HWND hwnd = CreateWindow("gldemo", "Demo", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 1920/2, 1080/2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        
        const PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {0,0, PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        SetPixelFormat(hdc, ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd), &pfd);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, wglCreateContext(hdc));
        
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    
    void (*glGenBuffers)(GLsizei, GLuint *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    void (*glBindBuffer)(GLenum, GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
    void (*glBufferData)(GLenum, GLsizeiptr, void *, GLenum) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
    GLuint (*glCreateShader)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
    void (*glAttachShader)(GLuint, GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glAttachShader");
    void (*glCompileShader)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
    void (*glShaderSource)(GLuint, GLuint, const char **, const GLint *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glShaderSource");
    void (*glEnableVertexAttribArray)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLuint (*glGetAttribLocation)(GLuint, GLchar *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glGetAttribLocation");
    void (*glVertexAttribPointer)(GLuint, GLint, GLenum, GLboolean, GLsizei, void *) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glVertexAttribPointer");
    GLuint (*glCreateProgram)() = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
    void (*glLinkProgram)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram");
    void (*glUseProgram)(GLuint) = (void*)wglGetProcAddress("glUseProgram");
    
    const char *g_vertCode =
        "#version 420\n"
        "in vec3 vertexPosition;"
        "void main() {gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition.xyz, 1.);}";
        
    const char *g_fragCode =
        "#version 420\n"
        "void main() {"
            "float res = 0.5;"
            "for (int t=0;t<58000;t++) {" // tweak this to make sure you're outputting ~10 fps. 58000 is ok for a gtx 1070. 
                "res = fract(sin(dot(gl_FragCoord.xy+res, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);"
            "}"
            "gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(res)*0.4, 1.0);"
        "}";
    
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    
    GLuint vertshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertshader, 1, &g_vertCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertshader);
    glAttachShader(prog, vertshader);
    
    GLuint fragshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragshader, 1, &g_fragCode, 0);
    glCompileShader(fragshader);
    glAttachShader(prog, fragshader);
    
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glUseProgram(prog);
    
    GLuint attribVertexPosition = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "vertexPosition");
    
    float verts[4*3] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f};
    
    GLuint vboId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*3*4, verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribVertexPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attribVertexPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 12, (void*)0);
    
    LARGE_INTEGER syncer;
    long long int waitfor = 0;
    
    for (;;) {
        //__asm__("int $3");
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glFlush();
        
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&syncer);
            if (waitfor>0) Sleep(waitfor/1000);
            glFinish();
        waitfor = elapsedMicroseconds(syncer)-500;
        
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
        
        MSG msg; char done = FALSE;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) done = TRUE;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (done) break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```